# Formula Error: =IF( SEARCH() ); Visual Reference to Question

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I know I'm very close with my formula: `=IF(SEARCH("Wednesday", (A3:A)), "workday", 0)`,

**But** I must be missing something here...: I can't get this formula to display the value "-" when I run it on a cell that is False. (I'm trying to paste this formula on every row to have a quick visual reference for whether or not that day was a workday. Currently my days off are Wednesday and Friday.)

Would anyone help me understand where this formula needs to be corrected?

P.S. I did look a little bit of searching on this website for about five minutes; is that enough time to warrant asking this question? I have also provided a visual reference to the Sheet itself.

Google sheets is so powerful, I had no idea. Fun to be learning this.

**Formula that doesn't work as expected**: `=IF(SEARCH("Wednesday", (A3:A)), "workday", "-")`

[image: An image of the formula =IF(SEARCH("Wednesday", (A3:A)), "workday", 0)]

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `"Wednesday"` (or `"Friday"`) you can use the `WEEKDAY` function in combination with the `SWITCH` function.

```
=SWITCH(WEEKDAY($A3),4,"workday",6,"workday","---"))
```

You can also add to this formula the `ARRAYFORMULA` function so your results will auto-expand for a whole array.

```
=ArrayFormula(SWITCH(WEEKDAY($A3:$A),4,"workday",6,"workday","---"))
```

---

**Functions used**:

- [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985)
- [SWITCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: Thank you for explaining this!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer; it took me a while to figure out how those formulas worked, but now that I understand ```ARRAYFORMULA``` better it's awesome!